# Monitor Windows services - Nagios

Tags: nagios, system-monitoring

In Nagios,how do I monitor Windows services that are running under a different user account and not under the local system account ( log on as)? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR, in order to monitor private services of machines, you need your NSClient++ to interact with machine's desktop. So it needs to be allowed within Local System Account. https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/monitoring-windows.html

At least, I can't find any other information about it atm.